# Using lambda to remove word occurences below certain times in a series of Python

Tags: python, lambda

I have this massive 41,000 series of rows in dataframe **df**:

```
column1                                   column2     column2
content in not below like this amsterdam  nan         sport
massive create non-programming question   nan         religion
```

I want to REMOVE ALL THE WORD OCCURENCES BELOW 5 TIMES OR EQUAL in **column1** so the **df** dataframe would look like this:

```
column1                                   column2     column2
content amsterdam                         nan         sport
massive create non-programming question   nan         religion
```

Anyone can help me please?

my initial attempt is like this:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(filter(lambda x : (x, df['column1'].count < 4)), set(df['column1']))
```

but I got error message says:

```
TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usual for people to write some code, and share that code to get help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry @Mikkel I forgot to put my code

Comment: `filter` takes 2 arguments, the function and an iterable to apply it to. At the moment you're only giving a function `lambda x : (x, df['column1'].count < 4)`

Comment: @Jack Zaki Zakiul Fahmi Jailani Is the data frame you're using from Pandas?

Comment: yes @SpiffyB. Could you help me?

Comment: i tried this code:
`pd.Series([x.strip() for x in df['column1'].str.split(',').sum()]).value_counts()`.

but only got the occurences of the sentence while I wanted the occurences of individual word:
`content Amsterdam                                        1`
`massive create non-programming question   1`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly how you want to filter the dataframe?

Comment: @SpiffyB simple: I want to remove **individual word** with certain **count of characters **  (for example the word _stack_ has 5 characters). I want to remove it using lambda and list comprehension in Python because I have 41,000 rows where some rows have even thousands of words. I figure out how to get all the words with words counts below 5 times, but then I have to remove that words from 41,000 rows recurringly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to use a function for this as a single lambda would be too complicated and not very clean.

The [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) transforms the elements to a list of words. Then a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) keeps the words that are greater than 5.

```
import re

def remove_five_or_less(line):
    word_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  line["column1"]).split()
    filtered_list = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 5, word_list)
    return " ".join(filtered_list)

df["column1"] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_five_or_less(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm @SpiffyB. The code does remove all the character counts below 5 times. But then I just realized that actually what I wanted to remove is all the keywords with words counts below 5 times from all the rows. Maybe you can see my new question here:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845910/remove-keywords-based-on-words-counts-fom-massive-python-dataframe)

Nevertheless, I will still vote for your answer. Thank youuu