# remove keywords based on words counts fom massive python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have this **df** dataframe with 41,000 rows contains thousands of words for example like this **df**:

```
column1                                                                   column2
better spotted better rights rights rights fresh fresh rights rights      2015
better rights reserved                                                    2016
better                                                                    2015
better horse                                                              2014
```

and I got the frequency of every word from **df** to **df2** with this code:

`df2 = df['column1'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()`

and my **df2** looks like this:

`keywords      counts
spotted        1
better         5
fresh          2
rights         6
horse          1
reserved       1`

Then how to remove all the **keywords** in **df** which has **counts below 5 times** based on **df2** so then **df** would look like this:

```
column1                                           column2
better better rights rights rights rights rights  2015
better rights                                     2016
better                                            2015
better                                            2014
```

my initial trial is to make list of keywords from **df2** like this:

```
ListKeywords = ['spotted', 'fresh', 'horse', 'reserved']
```

and then simply remove all that word within **ListKeywords** from **df** with this code:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (ListKeywords)]))
```

then I got frustrated because I have 15,000 keywords which has words counts below 5 times in all rows. Meaning that I have to put that 15,000 keywords into the **ListKeywords**, which is insane.

Anyone can help me out of this frustation? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you create `df2` it's easier to work with the `stack`ed Series prior to the value_counts. This allows you to filter it then `str.join` back only the words you want to keep.

```
s = df['column1'].str.split(expand=True).stack()

# Keep only words with frequency above specified threshold
cutoff = 5
s = s[s.groupby(s).transform('size') >= cutoff]

# Alignment based on original Index
df['column1'] = s.groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

---

```
                                            column1  column2
0  better better rights rights rights rights rights     2015
1                                     better rights     2016
2                                            better     2015
3                                            better     2014
```

---

For your own knowledge, if working with the `value_counts` DataFrame, you can subset it and generate `ListKeywords` by only specifying the cutoff. However, we've already `split` the `'column1'` Series to get the counts, so re-doing this calculation here is fairly inefficient.

```
df2 = df['column1'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()

cutoff = 5
ListKeywords = df2[df2 >= cutoff].index
#Index(['rights', 'better'], dtype='object')

df['column1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split(' ') if i in ListKeywords]))
```

---

Starting Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['better spotted better rights rights rights fresh fresh rights rights',
                               'better rights reserved', 'better', 'better horse'],
                   'column2': [2015, 2016, 2015, 2014]})
```

Comment: works like a charm man @ALollz .... excellent. Now I can get a nice sleep without having to put all 15,000 the keywords into list